# Pasarle un color en c#

Tags: c#

tengo codigo c# en mi condicional y necesito pasarle un color a un campo de texto. Pero nose cual es la función necesaria para pasarselo.

```
 else if(prueba == 2)
   { txtListaProcesos.Text


     }
```

Este es el ID de mi caja de texto donde tendría que pasarle un color. En mi caso no puedo usar css.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Es una propiedad del componente y no una función.

```
else if(prueba == 2)
{ 
   textBox1.BackColor = Color.Red;
   textBox1.ForeColor = Color.Blue;
}
```